# Using variable names in arrays to identify and save data to files

Tags: r

I have a series of data.frames in R that I would like to save as text files so I can share them with others.

Let's call the data.frames `a, b, c`, etc. I can write a simple loop to save these:

```
for (mydata in c("a",
                 "b",
                 "c")){
  write.csv(x = get(mydata),
            file = file.path("datadump",paste0(mydata,".csv")))  
}
```

However, some of the other data I want to save are lists; `l1, l3, l4`, etc. I want to use the same method to save the data, but I can't figure out how to just save one element. For example,

```
for (mydata in c("a",
                 "b",
                 "l1$x")){
  write.csv(x = get(mydata),
            file = file.path("datadump",paste0(mydata,".csv")))  
}
```

returns an error: `Error in get(mydata) : object 'l1$x' not found`. I've also tried referring to the lists as `l1[[x]]`, and that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: `l1$x` isn't actually an "object" strictly speaking, so `get` won't be able to access it. Something like `get(l1)$"x"` works, although is more difficult to deal with programmatically.

Comment: Try with `eval(parse(text = "l1$x"))`

Comment: @JulienNavarre: That works. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `eval(parse(text = "l1$x"))`

(Thank you)